# Macro works fine when I call it, but does not work while as .OnAction of a button

Tags: vba, excel

can anyone help me with he problem with assigning a macro to a button properly?

This is the macro I want to assign:

```
Sub TOP(table_sheet_name As String, sheet_name As String, chart_name As String, number As Integer)

Dim s As Series
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheetChart As Worksheet
Dim sheetTable As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sheetTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(table_sheet_name)
Set sheetChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name)

'delete existing series

'For Each s In sheetChart.ChartObjects(chart_name).SeriesCollection
sheetChart.ChartObjects(chart_name).Activate
For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    s.Delete
Next s

'add proper number of new series
'With sheetChart.ChartObjects.Chart(chart_name)
sheetChart.ChartObjects(chart_name).Activate
With ActiveChart
For i = 1 To number
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    sheetTable.Select
    With .FullSeriesCollection(i)
        .Name = sheetTable.Cells(11 + i, 1).Value
        .XValues = sheetTable.Range(Cells(11, 2), Cells(11, 25))
        .Values = sheetTable.Range(Cells(11 + i, 2), Cells(11 + i, 25))
        .MarkerStyle = 8
        .MarkerSize = 5
        .Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        .Format.Line.Weight = 2.25
        .Format.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
        .Format.Shadow.Type = msoShadow21
    End With
    sheetChart.Select
Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And here you have a part of my code where I try to make a shape-button:

```
Set rngB = ws.Cells(1, 5)
Set R1 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, rngB.Left, rngB.TOP, rngB.Width, rngB.Height)
With R1
    .Line.Weight = 0.5
    .Line.Style = msoLineSingle
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 102, 204)
    .Name = "TOP5"
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "TOP 5"
    '.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'TOP""Liczba_promocji"",""Wykres sezonowości"",""Wykres Sezonowości"",5'"
    .OnAction = "'TOP""Liczba_promocji"",""Wykres sezonowości"",""Wykres Sezonowości"",5'"
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
    .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 12
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = 32
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 102, 204)
    .Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    .Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1
    .Locked = True
End With
```

I have no idea what may be the problem, I have looked for the solution for some time already.
The error I get: "...the macro may not be available in this workbook(worksheet) or all macros may be disabled..."

I also need to note that when I call the procedure in the code it works fine:

```
Call TOP("Liczba_promocji", "Wykres sezonowości", "Wykres Sezonowości", 5)
```

Comment: Where is the `TOP` procedure located? in a module?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, yes, in the same module

Comment: are you sure that you are clicking on the correct shape? Remove old shapes before you test adding new ones, or test this code in a new workbook. I could not reproduce that issue. I copied your `.OnAction` and it worked as intended.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It indeed worked, when I copied my code to a new workbook, now it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
Sub testMacro(arg1 As String, arg2 As String, arg3 As Integer)
MsgBox arg1 & ", " & arg2 & ", " & arg3
End Sub
```

This macro assigned to the very same button with:

```
.OnAction = "'testMacro""arg1"",""arg2"", arg3'"
```

Works perfectly fine, so I think it is possible.